# Reverse for 'post_like_dislike' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post_like_dislike/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am building a Blogapp and Adding like , unlike buttons into it. BUT when i trying to open page, i keep getting this error.

> Reverse for 'post_like_dislike' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post_like_dislike/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$']

urls.py

```
path('post_like_dislike/<int:post_id>/',views.post_like_dislike, name='post_like_dislike'),
```

I don't what am i doing wrong.

Thank You In advance.

Comment: This is the typical error message if you use {% url 'mains:post_like_dislike' post.id %} with post.id empty

Comment: Try to check if post_id is in your Database.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your mains/urls.py have this line **`app_name = "mains"`**

Change your url to :

```
path('post_like_dislike/<pk>/',views.post_like_dislike, name='post_like_dislike'),
```

It should work for you now.

Comment: @Progam, If this answer became usefull to you then please mark this answer as "Accepted answer"  - thank you.